# Httpd(apache) is not starting on fedora 23

Tags: apache, server, httpd.conf, fedora-23

I so much tried to install nginx , but it didn't work. After that i tried install and configure apache(httpd) server on my Fedora23 dist. But my server doesn't want to be start namely it doesn't work and it returns some errors , when i try to start it: `sudo systemctl start httpd` *Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.* 
And after that i saw logs in `journalctl -xe`. it shows this:

```
    Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber audit[15981]: CRED_REFR pid=15981 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:s
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber sudo[15981]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber kernel: audit: type=1105 audit(1467095209.363:842): pid=15981 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber sudo[15981]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber audit[15981]: USER_START pid=15981 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber polkitd[900]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:15982:464115 (system bus name :1.256 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notif
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber audit[15988]: AVC avc:  denied  { append } for  pid=15988 comm="httpd" name="error.log" dev="dm-0" ino=1704951 scontext=system_u
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1467095209.491:843): avc:  denied  { append } for  pid=15988 comm="httpd" name="error.log" dev="d
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber systemd[1]: httpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=httpd comm="system
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1467095209.525:844): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber kernel: audit: type=1106 audit(1467095209.533:845): pid=15981 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber kernel: audit: type=1104 audit(1467095209.533:846): pid=15981 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber sudo[15981]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber audit[15981]: USER_END pid=15981 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:se
Jun 28 11:26:49 cyber audit[15981]: CRED_DISP pid=15981 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:s
Jun 28 11:26:50 cyber polkitd[900]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:15982:464115 (system bus name :1.256, object path /org/freedesk
Jun 28 11:27:15 cyber google-chrome.desktop[3111]: [1:1:0628/112715:ERROR:PlatformKeyboardEvent.cpp(117)] Not implemented reached in static PlatformEv
```

I did all steps like this [steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7)
Can anybody explain me **what is error and how solve it**  ?

[image: Virtual host file configuration]

[image: Httpd status]

**service httpd status**

Comment: What does your main http server error log file show?

Comment: (13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/shop/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Comment: But this file " /var/www/shop/error.log"  exists , and file owner is me max:max

Comment: That file should belong to root, not to your personal account. But fixing that won't solve your main issue I am afraid. It might solve that error in the log file, though.

Comment: You fixed that file ownership issue or not?

Comment: no , could not , i changed owner to apache:apache , but it didn't help too.

Comment: What about the other error log files? Try to strip down your configuration to just a default host, no virtual hosts by commenting out all stuff. Try again. Does that succeed?

Comment: and i forgot to write something, in actually server works , without `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`

Comment: my /etc/hosts file is: `127.0.0.1  localhost  
127.0.0.1  drupal  
127.0.1.1 cyber
127.0.1.1 nginxsite.com 
127.0.1.1 shopstyle 
127.0.0.1 shop 
::1  localhost
`

Comment: OK, so comment out the additional config files one by one. That way you can narrow down _what_ details causes the server to fail to start up. So you narrow down the cause. That should make it easier to find the actual issue.

Comment: []service httpd status

Comment: please share output of above command

Comment: I added on top as picture